# Got JdkVersion classNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-flex

I have Updated spring version from **4.2.3 to 5.0.2** and security from **5.0.1** to **5.0.10** and using spring-flex version **1.6.0.RC1**.

using BlazeDS Dependencies like this.

```
    <!--=| BlazeDS Dependencies |=-->
    <dependency org="com.adobe.blazeds" name="blazeds-core" rev="4.0.0.14931"/>
    <dependency org="com.adobe.blazeds" name="blazeds-common" rev="4.0.0.14931"/>
    <dependency org="com.adobe.blazeds" name="blazeds-remoting" rev="4.0.0.14931"/>
```

But i am getting following exception.

```
  SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_messageBrokerDefaultHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_messageBroker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: MessageBroker initialization failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/JdkVersion
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
```

Comment: Spring Flex isn't active anymore for about 3+ years. Basically it is abandoned and will not be updated to be compatible with Spring 5. The `JdkVersion` class has been removed in Spring 5 and as such Spring Flex will never work with Spring 5.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Flex Bean _messageBroker initialized failed. 
It seems it only support spring 4.X and JdkVersion is deprecated in Spring 5.X