# Apache Royale and JDK 8 compatibility

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, blazeds, spring-boot-starter, apache-royale

I'm trying to create an Apache Royale project with Java back end.

I've used in my pom `blazeds-spring-boot-starter` but I have a compatibility issue about the JDK compatibility in `org.springframework.flex.config.FlexConfigurationManager` class in the method `getMessagingConfiguration` in Spring Flex Core jar.

This issue has derived by use of JdkVersion class not presents in Java 8 (or greater).

How can I fix that?

This is my pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
    <artifactId>blazeds-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

So, I don't understand how Apache Royale can be used with JDK greater than 7.

This is my stackerror:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/JdkVersion
> at org.springframework.flex.config.FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration(FlexConfigurationManager.java:101)
> ~[spring-flex-core-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageBrokerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MessageBrokerFactoryBean.java:141)
> ~[spring-flex-core-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
> at it.uncertainty.KylixApplication.main(KylixApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4] Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.JdkVersion
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
> ... 26 common frames omitted

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058280/got-jdkversion-classnotfoundexception

Comment: and.. it is not the Royale part, it is the BlazeDs part

Comment: @ProgrammerDancuk: Hi dear, I know is a problema about Spring Flex Core (so BlazeDS) but on Royale pages, has declared Royale it's compatible with JDK 8 and newer version, and is strongly adviced to mantains the actual communication system (with BlazeDS). Apache Royale borns to replace the old Flex / Flash Player project to it. So I've supposed the Royale team has upgrades the BlazeDS project. In the past I've checked the BlazeDS git (1.6.0_RC) and I've changed use of JdkVersion (removing it by the code)

Comment: Well then you should open issue on Github instead to address this, this is the link https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/issues

Comment: @ProgrammerDancuk dear on SO it is possible open this questions. In other rings, obviously I can open further requests/issues. Thanks for the link